# Coercive problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

this is the complete problem

[image]

[image]

[image]
please do you know why :

there exist $w\in L^2(\Omega)~~\text{such that}~~|u_k(x)|\leq w(x)$ a.e in $\Omega$ and for all $k$ ?

please thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if $u_n$ converge weakly to u in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, then $u_n$ converges strongly to $u$ in $L^2$. To conclude, see [here](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~karch/analiza_nieliniowa/ref/BREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf) page 94 Theorem 4.9.

Comment: Hello, thank you , please do you know why :"but $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ so that $I(u)\geq m$ "???

Comment: Think on the definition of $m$.

Comment: yes $m=\inf I(u)$ so $m\leq I(u)$ , i dont understand why they say but $u\in H^1_0$ ,why the fact: $u \ in H_0^1$ is important

Comment: It is important beucause the infimum is taken within the set $H_0^1(\Omega)$. If $u$ does not belong to $H_0^1$, how can you say that $I(u)\geq m$?